# JNI debug: The currently selected Native debugger doesn't support breakpoints of type 'Java Line Breakpoints'

Tags: debugging, java-native-interface

The currently selected Native debugger doesn't support breakpoints of type 'Java Line Breakpoints'. As a result, these breakpoints will not be hit.
The debugger selection can be modified in the run configuration dialog.

and I debug on MAC OX

Answer (score 1):

Use IntelliJ ;)

https://youtu.be/8Cjeq4l5COU

This way, you can easily debug JNI ;)